# Crontab throws errors when starting python3 script

Tags: python, python-3.x, cron

I followed [this](https://www.instructables.com/Raspberry-Pi-Launch-Python-script-on-startup/) tutorial to start a python3 script at startup. The significant files are all stored at `/home/pi/Desktop`

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ ls
Jaeger.py  launcher.sh  logs
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $
```

There are three files in general:

1. `Jaeger.py` Python script which needs python3
2. `launcher.sh` Shell script which should be started after boot
3. `logs` Folder for log files when the cronjob failed

### Jaeger.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import sys
import curses
import mariadb  # => need python3!
from evdev import InputDevice, ecodes, list_devices
...
```

### launcher.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
# launcher.sh
# navigate to home directory, then to this directory, then execute python script, then back home

/usr/bin/python3 /home/pi/Desktop/Jaeger.py
```

### Crontab

```
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
# 
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
# 
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
# 
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
# 
# m h  dom mon dow   command

@reboot sh /home/pi/Desktop/launcher.sh >/home/pi/Desktop/logs/cronlog 2>&1
```

When executing the `launcher.sh` shell script via `cmd` (without `sudo`) it works!

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sh launcher.sh 
0011674128
Did it!
Last Inserted ID: None
```

When executing the `launcher.sh` shell script via `cmd` (with `sudo`) it doesn't work!

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ sudo sh launcher.sh 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Desktop/Jaeger.py", line 5, in <module>
    import mariadb
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mariadb'
```

And this is the exact same error message I run into while booting and using the crontab... After boot, I can read this error message in my log files stored in `/home/pi/Desktop/logs/cronlog`

**Why do I get an error with `import mariadb` when using `sudo` and why do I get the same error when using the crontab without any `sudo` `cmd`? Is the crontab always started as `root`? Do I have to setup python3 for `root`?**

### BTW

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python3 -V
Python 3.7.3
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ python2 -V
Python 2.7.16


pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ which python
/usr/bin/python
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop $ which python3
/usr/bin/python3
```

**EDIT0**

pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip list
Package           Version

---

asn1crypto        0.24.0
astroid           2.1.0
asttokens         1.1.13
automationhat     0.2.0
beautifulsoup4    4.7.1
blinker           1.4
blinkt            0.1.2
buttonshim        0.0.2
Cap1xxx           0.1.3
certifi           2018.8.24
chardet           3.0.4
Click             7.0
colorama          0.3.7
colorzero         1.1
cookies           2.2.1
cryptography      2.6.1
cupshelpers       1.0
docutils          0.14
drumhat           0.1.0
entrypoints       0.3
envirophat        1.0.0
evdev             1.4.0
ExplorerHAT       0.4.2
Flask             1.0.2
fourletterphat    0.1.0
gpiozero          1.6.2
guizero           1.2.0
html5lib          1.0.1
idna              2.6
isort             4.3.4
itsdangerous      0.24
jedi              0.13.2
Jinja2            2.10
keyring           17.1.1
keyrings.alt      3.1.1
lazy-object-proxy 1.3.1
logilab-common    1.4.2
lxml              4.3.2
mariadb           1.0.7
MarkupSafe        1.1.0
mccabe            0.6.1
microdotphat      0.2.1
mote              0.0.4
motephat          0.0.3
mypy              0.670
mypy-extensions   0.4.1
numpy             1.16.2
oauthlib          2.1.0
olefile           0.46
pantilthat        0.0.7
parso             0.3.1
pexpect           4.6.0
pgzero            1.2
phatbeat          0.1.1
pianohat          0.1.0
picamera          1.13
piglow            1.2.5
pigpio            1.78
Pillow            5.4.1
pip               18.1
psutil            5.5.1
pycairo           1.16.2
pycrypto          2.6.1
pycups            1.9.73
pygame            1.9.4.post1
Pygments          2.3.1
PyGObject         3.30.4
pyinotify         0.9.6
PyJWT             1.7.0
pylint            2.2.2
pyOpenSSL         19.0.0
pyserial          3.4
pysmbc            1.0.15.6
python-apt        1.8.4.3
pyxdg             0.25
rainbowhat        0.1.0
reportlab         3.5.13
requests          2.21.0
requests-oauthlib 1.0.0
responses         0.9.0
roman             2.0.0
RPi.GPIO          0.7.0
RTIMULib          7.2.1
scrollphat        0.0.7
scrollphathd      1.2.1
SecretStorage     2.3.1
Send2Trash        1.5.0
sense-hat         2.2.0
setuptools        40.8.0
simplejson        3.16.0
six               1.12.0
skywriter         0.0.7
sn3218            1.2.7
soupsieve         1.8
spidev            3.5
ssh-import-id     5.7
thonny            3.3.10
touchphat         0.0.1
twython           3.7.0
typed-ast         1.3.1
unicornhathd      0.0.4
urllib3           1.24.1
webencodings      0.5.1
Werkzeug          0.14.1
wheel             0.32.3
wrapt             1.10.11
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ pip3 list
Package           Version

---

asn1crypto        0.24.0
astroid           2.1.0
asttokens         1.1.13
automationhat     0.2.0
beautifulsoup4    4.7.1
blinker           1.4
blinkt            0.1.2
buttonshim        0.0.2
Cap1xxx           0.1.3
certifi           2018.8.24
chardet           3.0.4
Click             7.0
colorama          0.3.7
colorzero         1.1
cookies           2.2.1
cryptography      2.6.1
cupshelpers       1.0
docutils          0.14
drumhat           0.1.0
entrypoints       0.3
envirophat        1.0.0
evdev             1.4.0
ExplorerHAT       0.4.2
Flask             1.0.2
fourletterphat    0.1.0
gpiozero          1.6.2
guizero           1.2.0
html5lib          1.0.1
idna              2.6
isort             4.3.4
itsdangerous      0.24
jedi              0.13.2
Jinja2            2.10
keyring           17.1.1
keyrings.alt      3.1.1
lazy-object-proxy 1.3.1
logilab-common    1.4.2
lxml              4.3.2
mariadb           1.0.7
MarkupSafe        1.1.0
mccabe            0.6.1
microdotphat      0.2.1
mote              0.0.4
motephat          0.0.3
mypy              0.670
mypy-extensions   0.4.1
numpy             1.16.2
oauthlib          2.1.0
olefile           0.46
pantilthat        0.0.7
parso             0.3.1
pexpect           4.6.0
pgzero            1.2
phatbeat          0.1.1
pianohat          0.1.0
picamera          1.13
piglow            1.2.5
pigpio            1.78
Pillow            5.4.1
pip               18.1
psutil            5.5.1
pycairo           1.16.2
pycrypto          2.6.1
pycups            1.9.73
pygame            1.9.4.post1
Pygments          2.3.1
PyGObject         3.30.4
pyinotify         0.9.6
PyJWT             1.7.0
pylint            2.2.2
pyOpenSSL         19.0.0
pyserial          3.4
pysmbc            1.0.15.6
python-apt        1.8.4.3
pyxdg             0.25
rainbowhat        0.1.0
reportlab         3.5.13
requests          2.21.0
requests-oauthlib 1.0.0
responses         0.9.0
roman             2.0.0
RPi.GPIO          0.7.0
RTIMULib          7.2.1
scrollphat        0.0.7
scrollphathd      1.2.1
SecretStorage     2.3.1
Send2Trash        1.5.0
sense-hat         2.2.0
setuptools        40.8.0
simplejson        3.16.0
six               1.12.0
skywriter         0.0.7
sn3218            1.2.7
soupsieve         1.8
spidev            3.5
ssh-import-id     5.7
thonny            3.3.10
touchphat         0.0.1
twython           3.7.0
typed-ast         1.3.1
unicornhathd      0.0.4
urllib3           1.24.1
webencodings      0.5.1
Werkzeug          0.14.1
wheel             0.32.3
wrapt             1.10.11

Comment: Could be the user that runs cron job doesn't have access to the same pip packages. What is the output of `pip list`/`pip3 list` for pi user and for root user?

Comment: are you using `sudo crontab -e` by any chance?

Comment: @zaxishere I added the output :)

Comment: @TeejayBruno Yes, I used `sudo crontab -e` the content is shown unter heading Crontab.

Comment: Remember that `pip install` installs it for your user only,.  Do `sudo -H pip install mariadb` for global installation.

Comment: Jaeger.py is a blackbox.

Comment: One wonders what you must be doing inthe elusive Jaeger.py. Maybe it helps placing a line `DISPLAY=:0` near the top of your crontab.

Comment: But anyway, curses?, evdev? and all that from a crontab? Brrrrr...!

Comment: @Roadowl Is there a better solution than crontab? It needs to be started automatically after reboot.

Comment: `sudo crontab -e` will execute all commands as `root`. Try omitting sudo and running the script under `crontab -e`.

Comment: Looks like `pi` user has all the packages but not the root user. See comments from @TimRoberts and @Teejay Bruno. It's very likely that you are running root user's crontab rather than pi user's crontab.